# How to disable Plone 5 Toolbar for authenticated user group?

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

Scenario below:

- A user logs into my Plone 5 site.
- The toolbar shows up but they have no options to do anything with it because they are in the Authenticated Group.

They only get Authenticated access to view a few areas. How can I suppress the toolbar for certain user groups?  or what is the best approach to this?

Comment: you don't want to disable the toolbar or you'll leave your users without access to personal preferences and logout action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest approach will be using CSS. You can provide a conditional CSS that hide the toolbar:

```
#plone-toolbar-container {display: none}
```

A very simple approach for this is described in this article: http://datakurre.pandala.org/2015/05/plonecustom-for-plone-5.html

Please note: the toolbar contains also a section to personal preference, so removing it will also hide some user's features.

Comment: The CSS rule could be extended with `#plone-toolbar-container:not(.role-editor)` and then a line for any known role in the portal. That works, as long as one remembers to update the CSS when roles are added, probably even dynamically possible with SASS.

Comment: Sorry, that must be `body:not(.role-editor) #plone-toolbar-container`

Comment: AFAIK, this just makes the toolbar empty without collapsing it?

Answer (score 4):

A nice way is to use **roles and permissions**. You can hide the toolbar for the `Member` role only (and not Editor, Reviewer and Manager) by overriding the toolbar and defining your own condition that filters on the `ModifyPortalContent` permission.

Here is an example for when you are developing your own Add on that depends on *z3c.jbot*.

1. Put a copy of the `toolbar.pt` template in the `overrides` directory of your Add on. This is the path to the template: `plone/app/layout/viewlets/toolbar.pt`. Rename the new file to `plone.app.layout.viewlets.toolbar.pt` for it to work ([see plone docs](http://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/theming/templates_css/template_basics.html#overriding-templates)).
2. Customise the main condition in the template.

   ```
   <section id="edit-bar" role="toolbar"
    tal:define="portal_state view/portal_state;
                personal_bar python: view.get_personal_bar()"
    tal:condition="not: portal_state/anonymous"
    i18n:domain="plone">
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   <section id="edit-bar" role="toolbar"
    tal:define="portal_state view/portal_state;
                personal_bar python: view.get_personal_bar();
                checkPermission nocall: context/portal_membership/checkPermission"
    tal:condition="python:checkPermission('Modify portal content',context)"
    i18n:domain="plone">
   ```
3. Add some CSS to remove the padding on the body for the Member role only.

   ```
   userrole-member.plone-toolbar-left-default { padding-left:0 }
   ```

Now supply some new links for the user to `/@@personal-preferences` and `/logout` and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

There are also other ways to disable the toolbar:

- remove it from the diazo theme [base `index.html` file](https://github.com/plone/plonetheme.barceloneta/blob/1.6.14/plonetheme/barceloneta/theme/index.html#L21) and/or [the `rules.xml` file](https://github.com/plone/plonetheme.barceloneta/blob/1.6.14/plonetheme/barceloneta/theme/rules.xml#L99-L101)
- remove it from [`Products.CMFPlone` `main_template.pt`](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/5.0/Products/CMFPlone/browser/templates/main_template.pt#L54)

Note that while any of these will remove the toolbar, the `body` tag will still include a `plone-toolbar-left-default` CSS class that will cause the page to be padded (ie. there will be a toolbar-sized empty space). So the CSS for that has to be overriden, or
one has to override the [bodyClass method of the plone_layout view](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.layout/blob/2.5.16/plone/app/layout/globals/layout.py#L115) so that the CSS class is no longer generated.

The existing Plone documentation has instructions on how to make theming rules conditional or override templates conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

Plone 5.1 (dev):
My simple and **working** approach with CSS :

```
body.userrole-member #edit-zone {  
  display:none;
}
body.userrole-editor #edit-zone,
body.userrole-contributor #edit-zone,
body.userrole-reviewer #edit-zone {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

to do additionally:

- fix margins when toolbar hidden (body.userrole-editor.plone-toolbar-top-expanded ....)
- show dropdown (logged in user name: useractions) instead of toolbar

Answer (score 1):

In plone 5.1 we have the permission "Show Toolbar".

In your generic setup profile, add a file rolemap.xml

Here I show the toolbar only for users with the roles Editor, Site admin, Manager (hiding it from Members). Add Members to just hide it for Authenticated without the Member role.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rolemap>
  <permissions>
    <permission name="Show Toolbar" acquire="False">
      <role name="Manager"/>
      <role name="Site Administrator"/>
      <role name="Editor"/>
    </permission>
  </permissions>
</rolemap>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to have the Toolbar but not the `contentview` icons and link inside plone-toolbar-main, so I edited my toolbar.pt:

```
    <section id="edit-bar" role="toolbar"
     tal:define="portal_state view/portal_state;
                 personal_bar python: view.get_personal_bar();
                 checkPermission nocall: 
context/portal_membership/checkPermission"
     tal:condition="not: portal_state/anonymous"
     i18n:domain="plone">
```

....

```
<ul class="plone-toolbar-main">
      <div 
            tal:condition="python:checkPermission('Modify portal 
content',context)"
            tal:replace="structure view/base_render">
```